# capture non occured data from dynamic input data

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have data rules like given below

```
1|Group1|Mandatory|1st occurrence
2|Group1|Optional|1st occurrence
3|Group1|Mandatory|1st occurrence
1|Group1|Mandatory|2nd occurrence
2|Group1|Optional|2nd occurrence
3|Group1|Mandatory|2nd occurrence
4|Group2|Mandatory|1st occurrence
5|Group2|Mandatory|1st occurrence
6|Group2|Optional|1st occurrence
```

Here as you can see Group 1 is present two times for data record 1, 2 and 3. It means group 1 can appear min 1 time and max two times. And also can see the occurrence of that specific record under group 1 when it occurs.  Mandatory should occur always and optional is may or may not be occur in input data. But all needs to be captured ..what's missing

And here is my input column data. That's a only column am having in input data

```
1
2
3
1
2
4
5
```

Is there any way I could get result to identify which data set if missing according to data rules table from input data ? Like in this example, output should like saying Mandatory record(3) is missing from Group 1 in second occurrence. That's only available information would be coming from input data and data rules table.

If any things needs to be added to get desired result...I would like to hear..what it is. All suggestions are welcome.

Thanks

Comment: Which DBMS are you really using?

Comment: @GurV..Its oracle 11g

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think You need something like this:

```
with input as (select column_value id, 
                      count(1) over (partition by column_value order by null
                      rows between unbounded preceding and current row) cnt
                 from table(sys.odcinumberlist(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 4, 5)))
select * 
  from data 
  where status = 'Mandatory' 
    and (id, occurence) not in (select id, cnt from input)
```

<sup>**[demo](http://rextester.com/DYOJ20414)**</sup>

```
  ID GRP        STATUS     OCCURENCE
---- ---------- ---------- ---------
   3 Group1     Mandatory          2
```

Count how many times `id` appears in input data and compare result with mandatory occurences in your data.

---

**Edit:** explanation

```
select column_value id, 
       count(1) over (partition by column_value order by null
       rows between unbounded preceding and current row) cnt
  from table(sys.odcinumberlist(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 4, 5))
```

This part simulates you input data. `table(sys.odcinumberlist(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 4, 5))` is just simulation of inputs, probably these `id`s are in some table, select them from there. For each provided `id` I'm counting it's growing number of occurences using function `count()` in analytic version, so we have this:

```
id    cnt
---   ---
  1     1
  1     2
  2     1
  2     2
  3     1
  4     1
  5     1
```

Next these pairs are compared with mandatory pairs `(id, occurence)` in your data. If something is missing last `select` displays this row with a clause `not in`.

This is how I understood Your question, perhaps You'll need some modifications, but now You have some hints. Hope this helps (and sorry for my bad English ;-) ).

Comment: ...Thanks for your logic. It would be great if you could provide some detailed info using this logic into my requirement. I mean how its working ?

Comment: Thanks Ponder ...!! You are great ..! 

Comment: ..what if I want to compare data group wise only ? Like if you see first five records in input data they just belongs to group 1 only. But lets say 1 or 2 or 3 comes in any other group they would be counted in same group. I want them to be compare with their respective groups only...Any suggestion ?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't fully understand. I suggest You to ask the other new question on SO, please give us clear input data examples, describe logic and expected output. If your question is clear, understandable, you will get the answer very quickly, I think.

Comment: Stibons..please check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43123963/oracle-validate-input-data-with-given-data-structure-rules new question with more detailed information..!! Thanks