# Oracle: Validate input data with given data structure rules

Tags: oracle

I have table called data rules. Its given below with some explanation.

```
Data|GroupNum|GroupType|GroupMinOcc|GroupMaxOcc|DataStatus|DataMinOccWithinGroup|DataMaxOccurenceWithinGroup|IDX
ABC |GroupA  |Mandatory|  1        |    1      | Mandatory|     1               |       1                   |1
DEF |GroupB  |Mandatory|  1        |    1      |Mandatory |     1               |       1                   |2
GHI |GroupC  |Mandatory|  1        |    1      |Mandatory |     1               |       1                   |3
JKL |GroupD  |Optional |  0        |    1      |Optional  |     0               |       1                   |4
FFF |Group1  |Optional |  0        |    1      |Mandatory |     1               |       1                   |5
RRR |Group1  |Optional |  0        |    1      |Optional  |     0               |       2                   |6
MMM |Group2  |Optional |  0        |    2      |Mandatory |     1               |       1                   |7
PPP |Group2  |Optional |  0        |    2      |Optional  |     0               |       1                   |8
CCC |Group3  |Optional |  0        |    2      |Optional  |     0               |       2                   |9
SSS |Group4  |Mandatory|  1        |    2      |Mandatory  |    1               |       1                   |10
TTT |Group4  |Mandatory|  1        |    2      |Mandatory  |    0               |       2                   |11
```

Let me explain you this data rules first.

1) A group can have multiple data records
Here as you can see GroupA is having only ABC data and Group 1 is having FFF and RRR data.

2) A group can be mandatory and optional. It means a group will appear definitely if its mandatory. Secondly If its mandatory, then its data records also having mandatory and optional status.

For example: Check group4
This group is mandatory and its First data SSS is also mandatory. It means this group is mandatory and when it will occur this data should also occur. But second data in this group is TTT which is optional. No matter group is mandatory, but this data is optional inside mandatory group so it can occur from 0 to 2 times
Lets Say this group occur two times..It would look like this

Group4 Example: Valid

```
    SSS
    TTT
    TTT
    SSS
    TTT
```

Invalid Group4 occurrence

```
SSS
SSS
TTT
TTT
TTT
```

Its invalid because in second occurrence of group TTT is occurred 3 times but it should not exceed from 2

3) If group is optional it can be appear or cannot be.

So As you can see, GroupD, Group2 and Group3 are optional So after GroupC directly Group4 data also can come in input data..like this

```
ABC
DEF
GHI
SSS
TTT
```

I want to capture exact IDX number from Data rules table from their respective groups only, If input data dont follow the rules mentioned in data rules table.

```
For example 1st Input Data Example

ABC
DEF
GHI
JKL
JKL
SSS
```

As you can see here JKL is optional data in optional group. But if this optional group occurs this JKL should come only one time. But it came twice. So I want return that IDX number 4.

```
2nd Data Example.

ABC
DEF
GHI
TTT
```

Here it should return IDX number 10. Because from mandatory group4 mandatory data SSS is missing and in data rules its IDX is 10

```
3rd Example

ABC
DEF
GHI
SSS
SSS
TTT
```

In this also IDX return for SSS should be 10. Because Its occurred twice. And as you can see in data rules whole Group4 can repeat one time only and whenever it will occur SSS will come only one time. SO that's a error

Many errors can occur same time as well. SO IDX number needs to returned from their respective group data only from data rules table.

In input data, Only one column will come with data records only.

Note: Group data will appear only in series like mentioned in data rules from top to bottom. And can be appeared or not on the basis of definition mentioned in data rules table.

Any suggestions..how can I achieve this ?

Comment: Why in your example:  `Group4 Example: Valid - SSS , TTT , TTT , SSS, TTT` this group is valid,  even though it does not containt data from mandatory groups: GroupA, GroupB and GroupC ?

Comment: @krokodilko..this group is valid because Group4 is mandatory and should have to occur in input data. And this group should occur min atleast one time and max two times as mentioned in data rule table.After that once its occurred their data records should occur according to their data definitions mentioned in data rule table. Each group is independent of each other. I hope its clear now.